# Certain applications don't stay in Launcher

Tags: 10.10, unity

I can start up IntelliJ Idea using the commandline, which is a shell script that starts up a java process. It then appears in the launcher, as normal. I can select "Keep in Launcher", but it only remains there until I reboot, then it disapears again.

This is the only application I've seen that does this - Stuff already in the applications menu stocks around fine if I tell it to stay in the launcher.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6222/how-do-i-add-programs-to-the-unity-launcher

Answer (score 3):

Also reported as a bug for IntelliJ:  [Giving a name to WM_CLASS to enable better desktop integration](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-66540) . A  WM_NAME is not enough, because, e.g chromium-browser, or any other application could also have "IntelliJ Idea" in the titlebar.

Answer (score 2):

Docky has the same problem with Java applications and their entries in the dock. Following this advice should help in Unity:  [How to Customize Window Matching](http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=How_to_Customize_Window_Matching) .